# My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath returns the source directory once in a while

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have been running a newly developed application for about five weeks.  In this application, we copy some files into the bin/config folder (copy always) and then read them into the program.  We need My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath to return the bin folder for the application, and that is exactly what that code is meant to do.  Oddly, every fifteenth  run (or randomly, I mean), this call, My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, returns the correct folder but in the source code. That is to say, we are building a path with My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath and /config and once in a while this resolves to the config folder in the source code, not the bin folder.  What could be causing this?  I am using Visual Studio 2017.  I am running this from the IDE every time.

Comment: If you use My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath in more than one place, do you have code in more than one Project?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, I think this called and used in a few different projects.  It is used in the same way: get me a file in the config folder but in different projects.

Comment: If you could put the building of the config directory in just one place, it would be stable. E.g. you might have a "Config" project whose sole responsibility is to deal the config. Otherwise, you will have to find which project is building the wrong path.